# Is it possible to assign a value to an index of a Box object?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, pyautogui

I am using pyautogui, and the function locateOnScreen() returns a Box object. I would like to add 50 to index 0 of said object, as shown here:

```
yourhand_loc = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(...)
yourhand_loc[0] = yourhand_loc[0] + 50
```

However I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: 'Box' object does not support item assignment.
```

Is it impossible to do this? If so, how might I work around it?
Any answer is appreciated.

On a further note, I could not find any documentation on the Box object. Does any such documentation exist?

Comment: why do you try to do this ? It seems you can't do this. Can you use directly `yourhand_loc[0] + 50` in your code ? or keep in different variable - `new_loc_x = yourhand_loc[0] + 50`

Comment: @furas I'm using it because there is a constant image that appears to the left of information which I want, so I'm using pyautogui to find the location, and pytesseract to find the info.

Comment: I still don't understand why you want to change value in Box. Why don't you use `yourhand_loc[0] + 50` in rest of code.  BTW. if there is no information about Box in documenation then check source code and you will see what you can do. Maybe you have to create new Box with new values. Using `import pyautogui ; print(pyautogui.__file__)` you should get path to source code. OR maybe documentation has link to source code (ie. on GitHub)

Comment: BTW: when I use `type(yourhand_loc)` then it shows `<class 'pyscreeze.Box'>` - so this Box is from module `pyscreeze` and you would have to search it in documentation [pyscreeze](https://github.com/asweigart/pyscreeze). But frankly, I wouldn't bother this problem and I would use `yourhand_loc[0] + 50` when it is neaded.

Comment: using `import pyscreeze ; help(pyscreeze.Box)` I see it doesn't have official method to add value in position but there is hidden `_replace` and you can create new box `yourhand_loc = yourhand_loc._replace(left=yourhand_loc.left+50)`. All problem is it use `namedtule` to create `Box` and tuple can't change value - you have to create new tuple with new values.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem trying to create a new tuple but didn't work so i fixed it like this:

```
new_loc_x = int(yourhand_loc[0]) + 50
```

instead of:

```
new_loc_x = yourhand_loc[0] + 50
```

using (yourhand_loc[0]) makes it an int64 class that looks like not accepted by pyautogui so declaring it as int seems to work.
hope it helps.